# Изменить язык на английский

Tags: php

Есть конструкция на сайте для загрузки фото в БД:

```
<input type="file" onchange="document.getElementById('photo').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])" name="file" />
```

Как мне в ней заменить весь язык на англйиский?
Нужно заменить текст на кнопке выберите файл и пояснение файл не выбран.

Comment: а причем тут `php`?

Answer (score 1):

В основном сейчас это делают так: 
сам input оборачивают в lable и делают его невидимым. А стилизацию нужную указывают контейнеру (в данном случае: lable).

HTML:

```
<label class="fileContainer">
    Click here to trigger the file uploader!
    <input type="file" onchange="document.getElementById('photo').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])" name="file" />
</label>
```

CSS:

```
.fileContainer {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    border: 2px solid lightgray;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.2s;
}

.fileContainer:hover{
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.fileContainer [type=file] {
    cursor: inherit;
    display: block;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-align: right;
    top: 0;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/YuriiSpace/gzeL823h/15/

> А вообще `input[type=file]` - это системная кнопка и в каждом браузере
>   она выглядит по разному. Так же стандартный текст который внутри
>   кнопки он показывает на том языке, который указан в браузере.
>
> Браузер на русском = "Выберите файл".
>   Браузер на английском = "Choose File".
>   Браузер на украинском = "Виберіть файл".